# fft matrix-vector multiplication

Tags: matlab, fft, convolution

I have to solve in MATLAB a linear system of equations `A*x=B` where `A` is symmetric and its elements depend on the difference of the indices: `Aij=f(i-j)`.

I use iterative solvers because the size of `A` is say 40000x40000. The iterative solvers require to determine the product `A*x` where `x` is the test solution. The evaluation of this product turns out to be a convolution and therefore can be done dy means of fast fourier transforms (cputime ~ `Nlog(N)` instead of `N^2`). I have the following questions to this problem:

1. is this convolution circular? Because if it is circular I think that I have to use a specific indexing for the new matrices to take the fft. Is that right?
2. I find difficult to program the routine for the fft because I cannot understand the indexing I should use. Is there any ready routine which I can use to evaluate by fft directly the product `A*x` and not the  convolution? Actually, the matrix A is constructed of 3x3 blocks and is symmetric. A ready routine for the product `A*x` would be the best solution for me.
3. In case that there is no ready routine, could you give me an idea by example how I could construct this routine to evaluate a matrix-vector product by fft?

Thank you in advance,

Panos

Answer (score 5):

Very good and interesting question!  :)
For certain special matrix structures, the `Ax = b` problem can be solved very quickly.

**Circulant matrices.**

Matrices corresponding to cyclic convolution `Ax = h*x` (* - is convolution symbol) are diagonalized in
the Fourier domain, and can be solved by:

```
x = ifft(fft(b)./fft(h));
```

**Triangular and banded.**

Triangular matrices and diagonally-dominant banded matrices are solved
efficiently by sparse LU factorization:

```
[L,U] = lu(sparse(A)); x = U\(L\b);
```

**Poisson problem.**

If A is a finite difference approximation of the Laplacian, the problem is efficiently solved by multigrid methods (e.g., web search for "matlab multigrid").

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question!

The convolution is not circular in your case, unless you impose additional conditions. For example, `A(1,3)` should equal `A(2,1)`, etc.

You could do it with `conv` (retaining only the non-zero-padded part with option `valid`), which probably is also N*log(N). For example, let

```
A = [a b c d
     e a b c
     f e a b
     g f e a];
```

Then `A*x` is the same as

```
conv(fliplr([g f e a b c d]),x,'valid').'
```

Or more generally, `A*x` is the same as

```
conv(fliplr([A(end,1:end-1) A(1,:)]),x,'valid').'
```

Comment: Convolution should be circular!

Comment: Fourier transform has the property, that says `s(t)*g(t) = s(f)g(f)`, where `s(t)*g(t)` - functions circular==cyclic convolution in time-domain, `s(f)g(f)` - product of functions spectra in frequency-domain :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add some comments on Pio_Koon's answer.

First of all, I wouldn't advise to follow the suggestion for **triangular and banded matrices**. The time taken by a call to Matlab's `lu()` procedure on a large sparse matrix massively overshadows any benefits gained by solving the linear system as `x=U\(L\b)`.

Second, in the **Poisson problem** you end up with a circulant matrix, therefore you can solve it using the FFT as described. In this specific case, your convolution mask `h` is a Laplacian, i.e., `h=[0 -0.25 0; -0.25 1 -0.25; 0 -0.25 0]`.